# Append To Text File Each Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I am using this syntax to write errors to a text file for logging in my `Global.axax` - it overwrites each time and only logs the most recent error.  While this is helpful, it is not as helpful as I need it to be.  How can I log each error that is raised?

This is my current code that only logs the most recent:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Exception CurrentException = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    if (CurrentException != null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("HereAreErrors.txt")))
            {
            sw.WriteLine(CurrentException.ToString());
            sw.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: For logging consider using libraries like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), otherwise you can use [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you want to "append to text file" then there's a handy class and method [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, no need to manually reinvent the wheel with a logging framework. Do some research and find a good existing one, such as Elmah.

Comment: I am using IIS - will this Apache product work for that as well?

Comment: [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) is a software foundation. Their "HTTP Server" product is commonly called Apache but is not their only product. They create tools for other frameworks too. Of which log4net is one.

Comment: log4net works great with IIS. We use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated you're better off using an existing log tool to handle your logging. They have a myriad of features and, best of all, are maintained by someone else!

With that said, and in the interest of answering the question as asked, here's how to resolve your problem. It has the added benefit of creating the file if it doesn't exist.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  Exception CurrentException = Server.GetLastError();
  Server.ClearError();
  if (CurrentException != null)
  {
    try
    {
        File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("HereAreErrors.txt"), CurrentException.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer, this syntax pointed me in the correct direction, as File.AppendAllText takes two parameters.  But I had to convert my variable CurrentException from Exception to string before I could pass it in as the second parameter for File.AppendAllText.

Comment: Good catch. I fixed the method call to deal w/ the string.